# Groupby loop over, group second dataframe in the same loop

Tags: pandas, loops, group-by

Consider this same small example as follow-up to a recent post:

```
sd={"X":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Y":[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "Z": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
frame1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["X","Y","Z"],index=["A","A","A","B","B"])
```

I want to group "frame1" with

```
grouped_frame1=frame1.groupby(frame1.index)
```

Now I want to loop over the groups by:

```
for name,group in grouped_frame1:
     ...
```

However, I have a second dataframe

```
mean={"X":[21, 22, 23, 24, 25], "Y":[26, 27, 28, 29, 30], "Z": [31, 32, 33, 34, 35])
frame2=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["X","Y","Z"],index=["A","A","A","B","B"])
```

which I also want to be split into groups following the groups in frame1, in the above for-loop, since the identical groups (size, index) exist. How can I subset and use frame2-groups in the "grouped_frame1"-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your indexes are identical you can do this:

```
grouped = frame1.groupby(frame1.index)
for name,group in grouped
     print(group)
     print(frame2.loc[frame2.index == name])
```

Comment: Ok, that worked out. I had to consider some str.split on index before subsetting.